# DirectShowLib Capture Device in .NET 4 error

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, directshow.net

While using videocaptureelement in WPFMediaKit, I cannot run it with .net 4 VS2010 application, however the application runs fine in .NET 3.5 VS2010 environment.

The application just pop out without error (Although i catch exception in domain and application). Debugging into WPFMediaKit leads to error at

```
 hr = graphBuilder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview,
                                           MediaType.Video,
                                           m_captureDevice,
                                           null,
                                           m_renderer);
```

Removing the line above will make the application works fine in .NET 4 VS2010.

I have try to debug in sampleapplication in WPFMediaKit and the result is the same that application will exit without error when the application is debug in .NET 4. Recompiling WPFMEdiakit and DirectShowLib with .NET 4 does not work as well.

Searching in google leads to questions without answer.

This lead me to suspect DirectShowLib problem rendering the capture pin in .NET 4...

Any help please...

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
hr = graphBuilder.RenderStream(null, 
        MediaType.Video, m_captureDevice, null, m_renderer);
```

Comment: hi , traineeforlife, you know why it works if i remove the preview pin category or even capture pin cateogory from renderstream method? I currently need to put it to work so smarttee will be auto inserted into the graph